# Composition of rigid motions

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, function-and-relation-composition

Argue that the composition of two rigid motions is a rigid motion.

So $ T_{1} \circ R_1 \circ T_2 \circ R_2= T_3 \circ R_3 \space $ for some $ T_3 , R_3 $.

Determine formulas for $T_3$ and $R_3$

The idea makes sense but i'm not even sure how to start this argument.

Comment: Don't assume that we know what you're talking about. In particular, $T$ is probably a a translation. I would like to think that $R$ is an orthogonal transformation but you didn't say anything about it. Are you looking for a matrix solution or an analytic solution? Generally, unless you asked a really interesting question, you will get downvoted if you don't show what you have tried so far; even though it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I'd start observing that a rigid motion is defined as a transformation which preserves lengths (and orientations), so if each step preserves these, then so does the whole transformation.

If you actually want to combine multiple transformations explicitely, I'd do so using homogeneous coordinates. Write your translations and rotations like this:

$$
T_i=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&x_i\\
0&1&y_i\\
0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}
\qquad
R_i=\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\varphi_i & -\sin\varphi_i & 0 \\
\sin\varphi_i & \cos\varphi_i & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

Multiplying such a matrix with a column vector $(x,y,1)^T$ will result in the corresponding result $(x',y'1)^T$. Performing multiple such transformations in sequence can be expressed by multiplying the corresponding transformation matrices. So you can combine the matrices on the sides of your equation, use some known formulas to turn products of trigonometric functions into trigonometric formulas of the sums of angles, and thus obtain the parameters of the right hand side from those on the left hand side.